# Spring Application cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am experimenting with java Rest services using spring. I am basically following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ 
Everything  has been followed according to the tutorial yet I get the following compilation error: `"Application cannot be resolved to a type"` when running `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` 
I see no obvious reason for it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the relevant files:

 **pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
       <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.0</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>

           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>de.debeka.rzm.testingRest.App</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**GreetingController**

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(1, String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

**main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled the name of your main class. Change it to:

```
SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
```

it should do it. You need to provide the name of the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: LOL! Do you think I should delete this question since this was this obvious? Or it still might be of help somehow?

Comment: You can leave it, mark answer as correct if it was helpful. People make mistakes, sometimes it's not obvious;)